# Create CV ( Curriculum vitae ) based on mysite properties - workflow / timerjob?

Tags: workflow, document, timer-jobs, mysite

What's the best way to automatically create a CV based on users mysite?

We've thinking of placing all the properties we need in the mysite properties, and then create a CV in word and just map everything with a workflow. Since all users have their own workflow we was thinking of making a feature that deploys the workflow to the site collection.

Is there a better way to do this workflow? From central instead of having one workflow on each user?

Every MySite have their own document library where the users documents are placed. This so we can change the search display template to also include the CV.

But what's the drawback of doing this? Is there a alternative way you would preferred?

Comment: I'm thinking of doing something very similar but was thinking that maybe an SSRS report? You could easily extend the profiles pages with all the info you needed and then SSRS reports for constructing the actual, printable CV's? Failing that then maybe use a custom search results template?

Comment: @samLuxford-Watts One problem with only using UserProfile properties is that you cannot add aditional content. Ex if you are going to add a prosjekt(s) you ofen want to have a "from" / "to" time . Therefore we are using library to "solve" this.